# Java adding modified tokens into string

Tags: java

I currently have a program that individually converts tokens of a string into their piglatin counterparts. However, the program needs to insert them back into the string they were taken with, with ALL of the original characters in it.

```
Hasta la vista baby. - the Terminator.

Hasta
astaHay

la
alay

vista
istavay

baby
abybay

the
ethay

Terminator
erminatorTay
```

These are all of the words and their conversions. I tried a method directly placing them back in, however accounting for missing characters and different length made it hard for me to do that. I tried to insert characters based on the length of each token added up, but that ran into complications when there were more than 1 whitespace character. How would I insert these words back into the string so it looks like this:

```
Astahay alay istavay abybay. - ethay Erminatortay


    PigOrig = key.readLine();
    String[] PigSplit = PigOrig.split("\\W+");
    for(int i = 0; i < PigSplit.length; i++)
    {
        if(PigSplit[i] != null)
        {
            FinalStr += Piggy.vowelOut(PigSplit[i]); // VowelOut returns the converted word only, no trailing whitespace or punctuation
            lengthtot += PigSplit[i].length();
            FinalStr += PigOrig.charAt(lengthtot); // attempt at adding up the words and inserting the original punctuation that was in the string PigOrig
            lengthtot ++;
         }

    }
```

Comment: show your code then folks can suggest about what needs to change.

Comment: @SabirKhan added it.

Comment: do you know how to use HashMap?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama no. I am in a beginner java course and we have only covered the basics. The instructor expects us to solve this only using loops, arrays, if and other basic concepts

Comment: @SergeiLevashov I am still having trouble understanding what your input and output is.. can you explain a better please

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama in the first code block the first sentence, "Hasta la vista baby. - the Terminator." is inputed. Then it takes each word and modifies it, adding some letters if conditionals are true. what I am left with is the modified words being outputted, completely stripped of the punctuation. I need to then put those words back into the string. for example, terminator was changed into erminatorTay. I need to go into the original string and replace terminator with erminatorTay

Comment: are you allowed to use temporary array, that is another array to store the changed words?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama yes. Sprinters solution worked for me though, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, it is 'how do I replace each word with its translation in a string?' The simplest way is to use `String.replace`.

So if you have created a `translate` method then you could do something like:

```
String line = key.readLine();
for (String word: line.split("\\W+"))
    line = line.replace(word, translate(word));
```

The advantage of this approach is that you are replacing the words in the original string not putting the words back together again.

Also note that it might be easier to translate just using pattern matching. For example:

```
private String translate(String word) {
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("(\\w*)([aeiou]\\w*)").match(word);
    if (match.matches())
        return match.group(2) + match.group(1) + "ay";
    else
        return word;
}
```

Comment: Corner case: if you input containts both ‘be’ and ‘ebay’, ‘be’ will be replaced by ‘ebay’ and later *both* occurrences of ‘ebay’ will be replaced.

Comment: line = line.replace(PigOrig[i], Piggy.translator(PigOrig[i])); im surprised I didnt think of such a simple solution earlier, I my mind wasnt fully grasping how the arrays were working. Thanks for your solution, helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want to translate all the words in the input, my taste would be for building the new string from scratch:

```
    String pigOrig = key.readLine();
    String[] pigSplit = pigOrig.split("\\W+");
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(pigOrig.length());
    buf.append(translateWord(pigSplit[0]));
    for(int i = 1; i < pigSplit.length; i++) {
        buf.append(' ');
        buf.append(translateWord(pigSplit[i]));
    }
    String result = buf.toString();
```

Comment: its an assignment they are allowed to use basic elements like arrays.

Comment: In that case, is `System.out.print()` basic? Just use it instead of `buf.append()` and finish with `System.out.println()` (had I been the instructor, I would have given extra credit for good use of concepts not yet covered in the course).